# Validations not triggered during on click on submit button

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I would like to display `required`, min `1` and max `5` validations in following fields in material-ui dialog. At the moment I have added for one field, but some how validation is not displaying during on click on `submit` button in dialog. Could someone please advise me on how can i fix the problem.

demo link added here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-wood-3jrwu?file=/src/App.js

```
const App = () => {
  const [rating, setRating] = useState({
    ballshooting: "",
    dribbling: "",
    ballcontrol: "",
    sprinting: "",
    fitness: ""
  });
  const [ratingTotal, setRatingTotal] = useState(0);
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const { handleSubmit, register, errors } = useForm();
  const isMounted = useRef(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    isMounted.current = true;
    return () => (isMounted.current = false);
  }, []);

  const handleClickOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const onChange = e => {
    e.persist();
    const ratingValues = {
      ...rating,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    setRating(ratingValues);
    ratingCalculation(ratingValues);
  };
  const ratingCalculation = ratingValues => {
    const {
      ballshooting,
      dribbling,
      ballcontrol,
      sprinting,
      fitness
    } = ratingValues;
    const newTotal =
      Number(ballshooting) +
      Number(dribbling) +
      Number(ballcontrol) +
      Number(sprinting) +
      Number(fitness);

    const finalAvg = newTotal / 5;
    setRatingTotal(finalAvg);
    return ratingTotal;
  };
  return (
    <form className="ratingForm">
      <Button
        className="playerRatingBtn"
        onClick={() => handleClickOpen()}
        variant="outlined"
        color="primary"
      >
        Enter Player Rating
      </Button>
      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="skills-area">
        <DialogTitle id="skills-area">Rate the skills of a player</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          <label>
            <TextField
              autoFocus
              onChange={onChange}
              margin="dense"
              name="ballshooting"
              label="Ball Shooting"
              type="text"
              fullWidth
              min={1}
              max={5}
              ref={register({
                required: "Soccer ball shooting skill is required !"
              })}
            />
            <span className="newsErrorTextFormat">
              {errors.shooting && errors.shooting.message}
            </span>
          </label>
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            onChange={onChange}
            margin="dense"
            name="dribbling"
            label="Dribbling"
            type="text"
            fullWidth
          />
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            onChange={onChange}
            margin="dense"
            name="ballcontrol"
            label="Ball Control"
            type="text"
            fullWidth
          />
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            onChange={onChange}
            margin="dense"
            name="sprinting"
            label="Sprinting"
            type="text"
            fullWidth
          />
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            onChange={onChange}
            margin="dense"
            name="fitness"
            label="Fitness"
            type="text"
            fullWidth
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose} color="secondary">
            Cancel
          </Button>
          <Button type="submit" onClick={() =>
          handleClose(
            handleSubmit(calculateAvgRating(ratingCalculation(rating)))
          )
        } color="primary">
            Submit
          </Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </form>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Comment: have you watched this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PquWexbGcVc

Comment: @JonathanAkweteyOkine, Thank you, I have tried ` inputRef={register}` displays required fields, but unable to display the validation message. For that I have tried `inputRef={register({required:"Soccer ball dribbling is required !"})}` and display `<span className="newsErrorTextFormat">{errors.ballshooting && errors.ballshooting.message}</span>`

Comment: The video says about inputRef (register) but I am unable to see the validation message displays under each TextField.